# objective-c command line tool: return value to bash

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, bash, shell

I created command line tool (objective-c), and I need to store result of executing this tool in the variable, and pass it next to my different tool in bash script.

The result of executing my tool is simple NSString.

How can I do that?

I have red about NSPipe, but I did not understand how it works.
I coded following lines:

```
   NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
   [[pipe fileHandleForWriting] writeData:[resultSourcesList dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Also seems like my tool is performed asynchronously in bash script,
how can I execute 2 tools synchronously, and pass result of first operation to second?

**update:**

I tried next

```
$TOOL_DIR/second_tool -p="$3" | ./firstTool "$3"/compile_commands.json
```

but output of second_tool is printed before output of firstTool

Comment: When your plan is to pipe multiple commands together using bash, your commands typically just use stdin/stdout and you start the "pipeline" such as: `bash$ command1 | command2 | command3` (having as many commands in the pipe as necessary).

Comment: @mah so, can I just use NSLog?

Comment: No; NSLog() does not print just the text you want to send, and it doesn't guarantee output to stdout. You should simply use printf() instead. (When printing objects, remember you can `printf("...%s...", [object description]);` in those places you would otherwise `NSLog(@"...%@...", object);`)

Comment: Changing your question dramatically after it's been posted disrupts the flow of comments and answers already on the page; a new question is generally better! Addressing your update though, you have the tools backwards. The command pipeline is left to right, so in your example, the output of second_tool would be the input of firstTool -- something that sounds backwards from your expectation.

Comment: @mah Except that `[object description]` is an `NSString`. You need to use `[[object description] UTF8String]`.

Comment: I wrote a little library to ease the pain of Objective-C console apps: https://github.com/Linux-cpp-lisp/LCTerminal.

Comment: @Kevin that's right, I overlooked that. Thanks!